# overflow:hidden only works horizontally

Tags: overflow

I have the element like below which is nested within other divs.

'holder' contains content which is larger than it can display. But I want to restrict the content to be only inside of 'holder'. Otherwise when hold the mouse down and drag to the left/right border the content will be moved accordingly and this is not wanted.

So I apply the "overflow:hidden" style. But this only works horizontally not vertically. The content still overflowed downwards.

This is under IE8,9

Any ideas?

```
<div id="holder" style="background-color:white;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue solved with addition of "overflow:hidden;position:fixed" style.

without specifying "position:fixed" the container will be extended fully to accommodate the whole content. Setting "position:fixed" has no effect since the container already displayed everything.